# Macro on auto fill down

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I have this code

```
Sheets(“CE”). Select
Range(“L2:T2”). Select
Selection. Auto fill destination: =range(“L2:T83”)
```

I would like to have the Range changed to whatever the column A has. It should be flexible and auto adjustable.

```
Selection. Auto fill destination: =range(“L2:T83”)
```

Comment: Please tag with the overall technology. There are many environments that use macros.

Comment: There are several spaces in your code at wrong places and also these smart quotes `“ ”` are not excepted by VBA and must be replaced with standard quotes `" "`. Otherwise your code is no valid syntax and won't excecute!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any empty cells in column A then this should work fine.

```
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Sheets("CE").Range("L2:T2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:T" & lRow)
```

Comment: Hi I am having an error in the line you have provided

Comment: @Lyn Where do you get the error, and what kind of error do you get?